# Check if Sequence of Year and Month Is Complete (Without Gaps) Given Start and End

Tags: c#

The task is pretty easy and I have an iterative solution but I am thinking that there is probably a more efficient of cleaner solution. I have a list of objects which contain a year and a month property. I want to make sure every month from a given start year + month to a given end year + month is covered.

This is my current solution:

```
for (int year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++)
{
    int startM = year == startYear ? startMonth : 1;
    int endM = year == endYear ? endMonth : 12;
    for (int month = startM; month <= endM; month++)
    {
        if (!someList.Any(x => x.Year == year && x.Month == month))
            throw new Exception("List contains gaps.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your code work?  How has your testing worked out?

Comment: Actually just fixed a bug. Now it works

Comment: Lol, i just saw. hehe, i am going to delete my previous comment :-)

Comment: This isn't necessarily inefficient. The expensive part is the Any call since that would have to potentially iterate the whole list and you would do this many times. If that is a problem (depends on your list size), you could sort the list and then check the difference between adjacent elements (if greater than 1 month, there is a gap).

Comment: If you edited to include the whole method scope (and more context around it, for example why throwing an exception is ok here), this would be a nice fit for [CodeReview.se]

Comment: Oh tanks, didn't know that stack existed! @MathieuGuindon

Comment: Side note, you shouldn't be throwing `System.Exception` but an exception derived from it. That class should essentially be treated as abstract; literally _any_ other exception type is more meaningful =)

Comment: As @DeanJohnson said it may not be a bad solution - algorithms on ranges are tricky. If you really need the best known (or even just better) solution I'd check if non-language specific version has answers on [cs.se] or maybe even ask there (check their rules first, similar how you  do it on SO - https://cs.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: I think I would populate a `Dictionary<(int Year, int Month), bool>` with all the expected year+month combinations given the start and end years/months, then traverse `someList` only once to set the corresponding dictionary values to `true`, and then throw a meaningful exception if any dictionary values are left `false` after the traversal.

Answer (score 0):

The extension methods for DateTime below create a time series that can be used to solve your problem by joining with Linq - works for daily gaps as well.

This is a more extensible solution, not necessarily more efficient given it uses Linq vs interation.

**Usage**

```
void Main()
{
    var startDate = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
    var months = 36;
    
    //sample w/ 3 month gaps
    var monthsWithGaps = Enumerable.Range(0, months).Where(i=> i % 3 == 0)
    .Select(h=> startDate.AddMonths(h))
    .Dump();

    //usage
    startDate.GetTimeSlices(monthsWithGaps.Last(), true)
        .Where(d=> d.DayOfMonth == 1)
        .GroupJoin(monthsWithGaps, slice => slice.Date, set => set, (slice, set) =>
        new {
            slice.Date,
            set
        })
        .Where(result => !result.set.Any()) //identify gaps
        .Count(result => !result.set.Any()) //count gaps
        .Dump();
}
```

**Extension Method Implementation**

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static List<TimeSlice> GetTimeSlices(this DateTime date, int numberOfDays)
    {
        int count = 1;

        return Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfDays).Select(x => date.AddDays(x)).Select(x => new TimeSlice
        {
            Date = x.Date,
            Year = x.Year,
            MonthOfYear = x.Month,
            MonthOfSet = ((count - 1) / 30) + 1,
            WeekOfSet = ((count - 1) / 7) + 1,
            DayOfMonth = x.Day,
            DayOfSet = count++
        }).ToList();
    }

    public static List<TimeSlice> GetTimeSlices(this DateTime date, DateTime endDate, bool includeEndDate = true)
    {
        return GetTimeSlices(date, (endDate - date).Days + (includeEndDate ? 1 : 0));
    }

    public class TimeSlice
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int MonthOfYear { get; set; }
        public int MonthOfSet { get; set; }
        public int WeekOfSet { get; set; }
        public int DayOfMonth { get; set; }
        public int DayOfSet { get; set; }
    }
}
```